# If a function uses "this", does invoking the function from a child class include the properties of the child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual, json-serialization

I create a class that includes a function to serialize itself to a JSON string using the "this" keyword, this class is then inherited by a child class.

```
public class Parent
{
    int a { get; set; }

    public ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    int b { get; set; }
}
```

If an instance of the child class then invokes the ToJsonString() function, will the returned string include the properties from the child class, or only those from the parent class?

```
Child instance = new Child();
string serialized = instance.ToJsonString();
```

Comment: Did you *try it*? It seems like you'd get an answer a lot easier that way.

Comment: It depends on how `JsonSerializer.Serialize` uses its parameter. Inside Parent, `this` is a `Parent`. If JsonSerializer.Serialize uses compile-time type information, then it will be able to access `Parent` properties. If it uses runtime reflection, then it can access properties of the most-derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be tested see (code below).

The original version of `ToJsonString` has a `Parent` parameter and only serialises the `Parent` properties.
This can be remedied by overriding `ToJsonString` in `Child` with an identical implementation:

```
using System.Text.Json;


Console.WriteLine($"Using parent version of 'ToJsonString': {new Child().BaseToJsonString()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Using child version of 'ToJsonString': {new Child().ToJsonString()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Using better version of 'ToJsonString': {new Child().BetterToJsonString()}");


public class Parent
{
    public int A { get; set; } = 1;

    public string BaseToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
    public virtual string ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
    public string BetterToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, GetType());
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int B { get; set; } = 2;

    public override string ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

This yields:

Using parent version of 'ToJsonString': {"A":1}
Using child version of 'ToJsonString': {"B":2,"A":1}
Using better version of 'ToJsonString': {"B":2,"A":1}

**Edit:**

As Petrusion correctly points out, another - much simpler - solution would be to force the `Serialize` method to use the actual runtime type (see `BetterToJsonString`method above).

Comment: I would argue that this is absolutely needless code duplication. Now any changes to `ToJsonString()` have to be done in every single child, and every single child has to implement it correctly. Instead of making `ToJsonString()` virtual, keep it nonvirtual and just call the nongeneric version of `Serialize` and supply the runtime type like this: `JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, GetType());`

Comment: @Petrusion: you're absolutely right. I added your suggestion to the original answer for the benefit of anyone just reading the answer (and not the comments).

Comment: Very good. Also, I feel obliged to mention that even if the nongeneric version didn't exist and we couldn't supply the runtime type with a `Type` object, we could still achieve this behaviour in C# without code duplication. If only the generic version of `Serialize` existed and we wanted to always call it with the runtime generic argument instead of `Parent`, we could make use of `dynamic` like so: `JsonSerializer.Serialize((dynamic)this)`. This will work the same way as the `GetType()` thingee because dynamic does Double Dispatch for us